# Why must I reselect my USB microphone on Skype every time I load Skype?

Tags: skype

My (USB Audio Device) microphone works normally on other software like Zoom.

But after every time I close Skype, Skype no longer recognizes my USB microphone and this USB microphone no longer works automatically and spontaneously when I start up Skype.

Rather, every time I load Skype, I must go to microphone settings, select another microphone (Microphone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio) or default communications device, then *select* my USB audio device again from the drop down menu. Only *then* it works.

How can I avoid this and just have the microphone be recognized automatically? I use Windows 10 Home, Skype version 8.79.0.95 "the latest version of Skype" as at 9 January 2022.

> [image]

[image]

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski done.